# Restore Files Deleted with rm -rf on linux

Tags: linux, ext4, file-recovery

I accidentally deleted two folders from my home directory and I want to recover them. I don't want to use testdisk or ext4magic (they just don't work for me and are really annoying). Also I have not rebooted yet and I have 400gb free on my main hard drive and I am using ext4.

Comment: You might want to ask this over on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I use foremost to recover deleted files.

Comment: @Petepf would you write that as an answer instead of a comment? Comments could get deleted in the future, which could make your perfectly valid recommendation useless.

Answer (score 1):

I used `photorec` to recover files in the past. You can even add file signatures for unique file types.